# Representar en un JSON schema un atributo que puede ser de dos tipos diferentes

Tags: json

Estoy intentando desarrollar un JSON schema donde un atributo puede ser de tipo objeto, o un string con el valor None.

He aquí el ejemplo del json:

```
"predicados" : [
        {
        "predicado":{ "texto": "ESTADO == TRUE", "tipo" : "P" }
        },
        {
        "predicado":"None"
        }
    ]
```

Por lo tanto, ¿Cómo escribirían esto en un Schema?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un esquema válido:

```
{
   "predicados":[
      {
         "predicado":{
            "texto":"ESTADO == TRUE",
            "tipo":"P"
         }
      },
      {
         "predicado":"None"
      }
   ]
}
```

Aunque no le veo mucho sentido a la clave `texto` de tu primer `predicado`, siendo que podrías tener algo como: `"estado":true` o  `"estado":false` , en ese caso, el esquema quedaría así:

```
{
   "predicados":[
      {
         "predicado":{
            "estado":true,
            "tipo":"P"
         }
      },
      {
         "predicado":"None"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda